# Every matrix in $SU(2)$ can be written as: $P= I\cos \theta+ A\sin \theta$, $A$ on the equator.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-groups

How can I show that every matrix in $SU(2)$ can be written as: $P=I\cos \theta + A\sin \theta$, with $A$ on the equator?

Comment: Can someone help me format by editing this question?

Comment: Check that I did it correctly (is $A$ supposed to be inside or outside the $\sin$!?). For tips on how to do write math see [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Yes thank you for editing.

Comment: I'm still lost here though, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: A brute force method: write down the most general $2\times 2$ matrix: $P=\left(\matrix{a& b\\c & d}\right)$. Enforce $P\in SU(2)$, i.e. $PP^\dagger = I$ and $\det P = 1$. This gives you three equations for how the complex coefficients $a,b,c,d$ are related to each other. I'm sure there are smarter ways to do this though (see for example the [Pauli matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices)).

Comment: What is the "equator"?

Comment: I think it is all matrices in SU(2) for which the trace of A = 0.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Write down a general matrix

$$P = \left(\matrix{a& b\\c & d}\right)$$

and enforce $PP^\dagger =I$ and $\det P = 1$ which gives you three independent equations relating $a,b,c,d$ and use this to show that a general matrix in $SU(2)$ can be written (NB: not the same $a,b$ as above):

$$P = \left(\matrix{a& -b^*\\b^* & a^*}\right)$$

with $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$ and $^*$ denotes complex conjugation. Now rewrite $P$ as

$$P = \left(\matrix{\Re a& 0\\0 & \Re a}\right) + \left(\matrix{\Im a& -b^*\\b^* & -\Im a}\right)$$

where $\Re a$ is the real part of $a$ and $\Im a$ is the imaginary part of $a$.

Comment: Ok thank you.  So if I can show that SU(2) can be written as $P=(ab∗−b∗a∗)$, then this proves it right?

Comment: @Jimmy Basically yes. But you also need to split up the matrix in two as I have done and use this to define $\cos\theta$ and $A$ and show that $\text{Tr}~A = 0$.

Comment: @Jimmy What is $\gamma P(A)$ ?

Comment: OH wait no it is something different I am sorry I'll check my definitions and do it on my own.  Thanks for the help!